# Control Structure in looping in array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
int [] num={1,2,3,4,5};
LabExercise2 pass = new LabExercise2 ();
for(i=0; i<num.length; i++){
    System.out.print("Please Enter Your Hours: ");

    BufferedReader hr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    hour = hr.readLine();
    hours = Integer.parseInt(hour);

    if(hours >= 30)
        {
            wage = 26*hours;
            totalonemonth = wage*4;
            System.out.println("Total Wages for 1 week: RM"+wage);
            System.out.println("Total Wages for 1 month: RM"+totalonemonth+"\n");
```

Can you/anyone help me. i've a code here but question is i need to add up all my result in control structure (totalonemonth) all 5 but it didn't work. is there something wrong?

Comment: @NinaScholz done ma'am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your total variable to 0 and add to it each time.

```
    int totalonemonth = 0;
    for(i=0; i<num.length; i++){
        ...
        if(hours >= 30)
        {
             wage = 26*hours;
             totalonemonth += wage*4;
             ...
```

Another thing, you don't need an array for loop iteration. You can do this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: hours can be 30.5 so `totalonemonth` should be `float`.

Comment: hour has been parsed as integer: `Integer.parseInt(hour)`